# What's the best way to use a u16 as a seed for a PDA?

Tags: solana-program, rust, metaplex, anchor-client, anchor-lang

Does something like this work?

Rust:

```
&x.to_be_bytes()
```

JavaScript:

```
new anchor.BN(x, 'be');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to derive a `PublicKey` that involves a `u16`, it must still be provided as a `Buffer` to the `PublicKey#findProgramAddress` function.

Based on the size of the number, in this case `2` bytes, you should allocation that space for an empty `Buffer` and then write the appropriate bytes into it.

```
const seedValue = 100 // whatever the seed value should be for the `u16`
const buf = Buffer.alloc(2) // u16 is 2 bytes in size
buf.writeUInt16BE(seedValue) // or `writeUInt16LE` for little endian
```

This `buf` can now be provided to the function for public key derivation.

Answer (score 3):

Using a u16 as part of the seeds for a PDA works like this:

Rust

```
seeds = [.., x.to_le_bytes().as_ref()]
```

Javascript

```
x = 12;
[.., new anchor.BN(x).toBuffer('le', 2)]
```

We use the `2` argument because a u16 is 2x a u8